# How do I save settings as a hash in a external file?

Tags: ruby

Can I somehow use this

```
settings = { 

   'user1' => { 'path' => '/','days' => '5' },
   'user2' => { 'path' => '/tmp/','days' => '3' }
}
```

in a external file as settings?

How can I include this into my script?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The most common way to store configuration data in Ruby is to use YAML:

`settings.yml`

```
user1:
  path: /
  days: 5

user2:
  path: /tmp/
  days: 3
```

Then load it in your code like this:

```
require 'yaml'
settings = YAML::load_file "settings.yml"
puts settings.inspect
```

You can create the YAML file using `to_yaml`:

```
File.open("settings.yml", "w") do |file|
  file.write settings.to_yaml
end
```

---

That said, you can include straight Ruby code also, using `load`:

```
load "settings.rb"
```

However, you can't access local variables outside the file, so you would have to change your code to use an instance variable or a global variable:

`settings.rb`

```
SETTINGS = { 
 'user1' => { 'path' => '/','days' => '5' },
 'user2' => { 'path' => '/tmp/','days' => '3' }
}
@settings = { 'foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2 }
```

Then load it thus:

```
load "settings.rb"
puts SETTINGS.inspect
puts @settings.inspect
```

Comment: Good answer, but you are forgetting `eval`

Comment: @glebm: Yes, and on purpose. I use `eval` when it's the only option available, not otherwise.

Comment: true, but just so that the reader knows his enemy I'd mention it :)

Comment: @LarsHaugseth You showed how to load a ruby file used for configuration but how do you save the settings back?

Comment: @PICyourBrain If you require your settings to be modifiable, I'd definitely go for YAML or some other serialization format instead of using files with Ruby code.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use [Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html)

```
settings = {
   'user1' => { 'path' => '/','days' => '5' },
   'user2' => { 'path' => '/tmp/','days' => '3' }
}
data=Marshal.dump(settings)
open('output', 'wb') { |f| f.puts data }
data=File.read("output")
p Marshal.load(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

A really simple one is to use eval.

**config.txt**

```
{ 
   'user1' => { 'path' => '/','days' => '5' },
   'user2' => { 'path' => '/tmp/','days' => '3' }
}
```

**program.rb**

```
configuration = eval(File.read("./config.txt"))
puts configuration['user1']
```