# How to convert a nested hash which is in string back into a hash?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, hash, nested

I stored my *nested hash* in a file, and while retrieving it, I want to it back in a **hash** form instead of **string**. When I read a file it will give me a **string** and then how can I parse it back to a **hash**. 
This is the string hash in the file:

```
{"SONGS"=>{1=>["2018-05-29 18:19:14 +0530", "HAPPY", "Meri Sapnon Ki Rani"]}}
```

Comment: what do you mean, that data is already a hash

Comment: Data was in hash and I wrote it to file. After reading it from the same file, how can I parse back to hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Already in SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object)

**WARNING SECURITY RISK!**

For your string you need to pass to `eval`, but this is a **[SECURITY RISK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637431/5239030)**

```
string = '{"SONGS"=>{1=>["2018-05-29 18:19:14 +0530", "HAPPY", "Meri Sapnon Ki Rani"]}}'
p eval(string).class
```

If you need to store data structures in files, I suggest you to take a look at YAML module. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30718500/5239030), for example.

**As suggested in comments:**

- Consider also security concerns, [look this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637431/5239030).
- Consider to change a little bit the string syntax to use a JSON structure. See below.

Use of JSON:

```
require 'json'
json_string = '{"songs":{"1":{"date": "2018-05-29 18:19:14 +0530", "title":"HAPPY", "name":"Meri Sapnon Ki Rani"}}}'
p JSON::parse(json_string).class
```

Comment: only if you don't have any security concerns, which is never the case I assume

Comment: Always prefer `JSON#parse` over `eval`.

Comment: @Subash, good point I edited. Thanks.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thanks for the suggestion, I added the point, changing the string to be compliant with the format.

Comment: Never use "eval", it should not even be there in the answer as first option.
"eval" is a security risk!

Comment: @pascalbetz, picked up your warning. I added an alert for security risk. But I replied to the question and to the string as provided JSON::parse doesn't apply.